# Getting Time Complexity and Space Complexity From a Program

Tags: java, compiler-construction

I am creating a website (my Academic Project) in which user can upload his program files (.cs,.PHP,.java), then the web compiles the program and able to say Time and space complexity automatically.  Is this possible?  How can we calculate complexity of program.  Is there any code in Java for finding complexity of a program? Or can we found these from compiler itself?

Comment: Have you asked your mentor about this? What have you found on internet? Or maybe you want people in SO start doing your homework?

Comment: It is not even possible to calculate if a given program will ever terminate.

Comment: The complexity is only defined if you give some parameters which can varies. You will have to go through the hurdle of defining which one can be a good parameters. And there are several types of time complexity (worst case, amortized), and space complexity (additional, overall, sometimes have to consider stack) - and a number of them need rigorous proof to come up with. It's not that simple a problem - and may worth a research topic.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you know what kind of input to give the program, you can *estimate* the complexity through successive iterations of actually running the program.  However, general case static analysis is impossible, due to the [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

If you can run the application multiple times on input sets of various sizes, you can develop an approximation.

In the classic case of sorting numbers, you can have the application sort a list of 2 numbers, then 4, 8, 16, 32, etc... and essentially graph the memory and time requirements for each run.   Basic curve fitting will show you the growth in complexity.

Note that this is not rigorously accurate, as certain algorithms may have points at which their performance changes radically.  Such a system may also get fooled by the differences between growths that "look" similar, but have vastly different properties, such as asymptotic and logarithmic curves, or exponential and polynomial curves.

Answer (score 2):

Determining the time- and space complexity of a program is a hard problem. As the feedback have pointed out, it is not even possible in general to point out if a program will terminate. (This is known as [the Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem))

To make a start with your project I would advice to look into [Cyclomatic Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) which is calculated for example by the GMetrics project.

This will get you started in your exploration of the subject matter.

Comment: Good advice start from t=a simple algorithm and advance... Saves his ass even if he mucks up everything that comes after!